# Custom UILabel-Subclass does not appear in dropdown selection of IB

Tags: xcode, swift, inheritance, interface-builder, uilabel

I wrote a tiny class that inherits from `UILabel`

```
import UIKit

class ConnectionStateLabel: UILabel, BTConnectionStateChangedDelegate {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    func didConnect() {
        self.text = "Connected"
    }

    func didDisconnect() {
        self.text = "Disconnected"
    }
}
```

As far as I know, in `Xcode` that class should now be selectable from the dropdown menu (section "Custom Class") for any `UILabel` that I drag into my `story board`, but it does not show up. What is wrong with that `class`? What did I miss?

Comment: click on your label, click on identity inspector. In class field, type "ConnectionSt", your class will be visible in suggestions. Just typing Conn would be sufficient.

Comment: That is exactly the problem: It is not working! My class does not show up there!

Comment: Can't say I have ever faced such a situation. Are your class and the storyboard in question in the same bundle? Have you tried cleaning the project (cmd+k)?